# Adafruit Anemometer

Tags: simulation, ltspice, pspice

Recently I bought an anemometer from Adafruit. I was wondering is there is any way or approach which I can simulate the sensor for measuring the wind speed. If there is any software able to simulate it, such as PSpice, LtSpice etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't read Chinese, but I suspect the datasheet says that the output impedance is less than \$200\Omega\$ and the output voltage is between 0.4V and 2.0V.... I think ANY simulation software can simulate that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is simply an analog voltage source (400mV to 2V), and you can model it as such. To model it more accurately, you should include a series resistance (output impedance, if you want to think of it like that), but because the datasheet is unintelligible, you'll have to ballpark it. Maybe 250Ω?

Any circuit simulation software can simulate a voltage source. (Or, if there's one that can't, let me know).